# Create and append data to spark graphx java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I have Java objects **Transaction(Object buyer, Object dealer, Int payed)** into java spark application and i want to make a graph (with graphx) where Vertex are buyers and dealers, and payed are the edges.
Furthermore, how can I add another incoming transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a graph manually with providing required `vertices` and `edges`:

```
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Long, String>> vertices = sc.parallelize(new 
     Lists.newArrayList({
      Tuple2(1L, "one"), Tuple2(2L, "two"),
      Tuple2(3L, "three"), Tuple2(4L, "four")})
    );

    JavaRDD<Edge> relationships =
      sc.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList({
        Edge(1L, 2L, 1.0), Edge(1L, 4L, 2.0),
        Edge(2L, 4L, 3.0), Edge(3L, 1L, 1.0),
        Edge(3L, 4L, 5.0)}
      );

Graph(relationships, vertices, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(), stringTag, stringTag);
```

Also, you can apply this approach to `CSV`, `TSV` or any convenient for you file format.

If you want to use `Dataframe API` for data processing with graphs, you definitely should take a look at [GraphFrames](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html).

**UPD**

1. *how can i initialize it in java?*

import `Graph` class:

`import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph`

[Graph](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/graphx/package-summary.html) is typed with vertex and edges types - `Graph<VD,ED>` so you initialize this class with vertices, edges, storage level and type tag - it's a requirement from Java API in Scala you can specify just vertices and edges.

```
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\softwares\\Winutils");
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("graph");
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        ClassTag<String> stringTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class);


        List<Edge<String>> edges = new ArrayList<>();

        edges.add(new Edge<String>(1, 2, "Friend1"));
        edges.add(new Edge<String>(2, 3, "Friend2"));
        edges.add(new Edge<String>(1, 3, "Friend3"));
        edges.add(new Edge<String>(4, 3, "Friend4"));
        edges.add(new Edge<String>(4, 5, "Friend5"));
        edges.add(new Edge<String>(2, 5, "Friend6"));


        JavaRDD<Edge<String>> edgeRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(edges);


        Graph<String, String> graph = Graph.fromEdges(edgeRDD.rdd(), "",StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(), stringTag, stringTag);


        graph.vertices().toJavaRDD().collect().forEach(System.out::println);
```

2. *when a new transaction has come, the idea is add it to graph, there is a method like "add" to graph?*

Apache Spark RDDs are not designed for fine-grained updates. All the operations on RDDs are about changing the whole RDD. If you have a large graph for the update operation it can lead to a huge memory consumption because of a frequent [shuffle operation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-shuffle.html). But if you want to reconstruct a graph not frequently you can simply copy vertices/edges from a previous Graph instance and append updates to it. If your use case is frequent data updates, you probably better off using a different approach - handle updates on DB side: `Cassandra`, `HBase` are designed for robust insert/update operations, if you need to store a graph in DB - consider `Neo4J`.

You can combine the usage of NoSQL DB mentioned above with Spark GraphX - fetching data to `Graph` by a scheduler, some signal, a message from Kafka etc. via `Spark SQL` and further loading to `Graph` and necessary processing (I have [the example](https://github.com/arukavytsia/spark-graphx) of this step with most popular algorithms with scala, it wouldn't hard to move to java).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i'm looking for java example.

Comment: Thanks Artem, but Graph how can i initialize it in java? and then, i'm in a spark streaming context, when a new transaction has come, the idea is add it to graph, there is a method like "add" to graph? i'm new in this wolrd!

Comment: @BlackCode I had answered both your question under **upd** section, please, check it.

Comment: thanks. Helped me a ton! So, when a new dstream with rdds are coming, get last graph from Neo4j, merge it with new transactions and save it!

Comment: hi @Artem is it possible to store created graph to disk, which can loaded later for querying  purpose